A formula for derivative of exponential operator
Let $\mathbb{R} \ni t \mapsto iA(t)$ a family of self-adjoint (not necessarily bounded) maps and consider the exponential operators $e^{\pm i (iA(t))} = e^{\mp A(t)}$. I am trying to prove that:
$$\bigg{(}\frac{d}{dt}e^{-A(t)}\bigg{)}e^{A(t)} = -\int_{0}^{1}d\tau e^{-\tau A(t)}\bigg{(}\frac{dA(t)}{dt}\bigg{)}e^{\tau A(t)},$$
but I can't prove it. I tried using something like:
$$\bigg{(}\frac{d}{dt}e^{-A(t)}\bigg{)}e^{A(t)}  = -e^{-A(t)}\bigg{(}\frac{dA(t)}{dt}\bigg{)}e^{A(t)} $$
and writing the right hand side as an integral, but I got nowhere so far.

See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_of_the_exponential_map#Statement
